# Can I contract "Where are"?

Tags: contractions

Can I contract *"Where are"* to *"Where're"*?

Even if it's not *wrong*, it's unusual?

Comment: See [**Using the contraction of “are”**](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36532/using-the-contraction-of-are)

Comment: This is a bit off-topic, but English contractions can get [weird](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_double_contractions)

Comment: It's pretty common in spoken English. When transcribed, often people will write "Where you going?" or "Where ya going?" instead of "Where're you going?".

Comment: @ScottSEA Thanks for the link, the awkwardness of *where're* is nothing compared to those!

Comment: @talles Out of those, the ones that reduce both "not" and "have" are probably the most common, but I think they are more common in British English (mightn't've, wouldn't've, etc). Also, where I live in the Deep South, "d'y'all" is quite common. There are many that I have never even seen or conceived of on that list though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not as unusual as you think, and it's not even very awkward to say (at least to me, being a native English speaker).

It is indeed contracted just like that, "where're."

"Where're you going?" is probably the most common usage.
Remember contractions are always considered at least a little informal, so don't say this if you're trying to deliver grave news or a formal speech.

I don't keep statistics, but if I had to guess I would say that where're is not as popular as it once was in vernacular. I think it's also more commonly said by children, who sometimes slur syllables together since they're not as experienced using the language.

Comment: +1 Note that this is eye dialect and doesn't reflect the actual pronunciation, which is more like /'hwɛɹ̥/, with an extended /ɛ/ and a strongly syllabic /ɹ̥/

Answer (score 4):

In informal spoken English, sure. But I wouldn't use the contraction in written English (I never see it written), unless you're writing dialogue.

Comment: Yeah, people don't write *where're* very much, even though reducing *are* in speech is very common.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's fine.

Note that in non-rhotic English, "where're" is pronounced "where-ə"

"Where-ə you going?"